# copy selected items from a multi-select list to other multi-select list

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have 2 multi-select lists in which i want to be able to copy selected items from the list to the other list.
I only want to modify properties on the viewmodel until clicking on the "save" button and post to the controller thru ajax call or knockout post.

Is there any way that i can achieve this?

Thanks on forehand!

jsfiddle:

```
    'http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/1420/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to set a variable to the value of 'this' in your viewmodel into order to be able to access the other observable array:

```
var SProcsViewModel = function () {
     var self=this;
```

otherwise on your "copy to DB2" button the value of this will be Window, not your viewmodel.

Then, copying from one observable array to another like this:

```
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function(value){
        console.log(value,this,self.storedProceduresInDB2);
       sprocs.push(value);
    });
```

The arrayForEach of knockout utils, loops through the observable array cleanly, and value will be the  array item, not the index of the array (like $.each).

(it's well worth looking further into ko.utils in the documentation too : [ko utils docs](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)

You can do the loop with $.each like this:

```
$.each(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function(value){
        console.log(value,self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1()[value]);
       sprocs.push(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1()[value]);
    });
```

Notice it's a bit more complex as you have to worry about accessing the observable array first and then the index of that array.

As you are adding the selected items from the list to a new array `sprocs`, you then try to push them to an array, but as there will be multiple items, you need to use apply:

```
self.storedProceduresInDB2.push.apply(self.storedProceduresInDB2,sprocs);
```

This will merge the 2 arrays.

Then you will have the selected items in the list and you can then call your AJAX code to do the update when you're ready.

I have created a fiddle with the above changes. http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/7zp5K/

UPDATE: to only add items to the selected list if not already there:

```
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function(value){
            console.log(value,self.storedProceduresInDB2);
            var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.storedProceduresInDB2(), function(item) {
                return value === item;
            });
            if (!match){
               sprocs.push(value);
            }
       });
```

this uses the ko.utils arrayFirst, that loops through all the items in the list, and if the item is found returns true.

we then check if match is undefined (not found) with !match, and if so (it's not in the list), add it to the list

I have updated the fiddle to include this code.

ADDED: In response to Henrick question in the comments regarding changing the code to use JSON objects instead of just ids....:

Remove the optionsValue:'Id' parameter from the `<select>` (both of them):

from:

```
<select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:storedProceduresInDB1, 
optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', selectedOptions:selectedStoredProceduresInDb1"> </select>
```

to:

```
<select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:storedProceduresInDB1, 
optionsText: 'Name', selectedOptions:selectedStoredProceduresInDb1"> </select>
```

This binds the selected items to the object themselves, rather than the Id property of the object.

Then in the code you must look for a match on the Id property of the selected item (now the full object)

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.storedProceduresInDB2(), function(item) {
            console.log('item in storedProceduresInDB2',value,item);
            return value.Id === item.Id;  //match to the Id property of the selected object
        });
```

See new working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/7zp5K/

Comment: in the ko foreach, i only want to add selected item to sprocs once and not duplicates. Is it something like this i need to do then:        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function(value){
            console.log(value,this,self.storedProceduresInDB2);
            
           if(!sprocs.contains(value))
           sprocs.push(value);
        });

Comment: Hi again, if i change the string into json objects it will not work ? http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/27/

Comment: Welcome Henrik - more of a 'squire' than a king though, but thanks :)